# Unable to attach remote debugger to app in PCF

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, ssh, pcf

I have multiple applications running in PCF and can remote debug in to all but one of them.  I use the same configuration making sure that 
JBP_CONFIG_DEBUG: {enabled: true}
is properly set and picked up by the app.

I run cf ssh -N -T -L 8000:localhost:8000  in command line and verify in PCF Apps Manager that the ssh session is established.

When I run the debug session in Intellij I get the error in Intellij.

Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"

And this error in CMD.

connect to localhost:8000 failed: ssh: rejected: connect failed (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: getsockopt: connection refused)

I can ssh into the app with cf ssh  with no issue.

I am not sure what the problem is or if there is something I am missing, but this same process work for the other applications.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What are the JVM options for the app to start it in debug mode on port 8000?

Comment: Command line args-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

Comment: Can you telnet to this port from the host machine?

Comment: You run: cf ssh -N -T -L 8000:localhost:8000
But cf ssh needs an application to run this through, correct?
Next to that, the syntax is localhost:port:externalhost:port, so you use localhost as external host

Comment: Coming to this question nearly five years after it was asked, did you ever find the solution?